# Is there a way to add an image at the beginning of the video using Python?

Tags: python, image, video

I wanted to ask, is there a way to add an image at the beginning of a video using Python? I heard that OpenCV library adds a group of images to produce a video but dunno a way to actually add an image to an existing video.

Comment: if you have access to ffmpeg, you could do something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350607/ffmpeg-add-text-frames-to-the-start-of-video (you'll need to make the image into a video and concatenate them)

Comment: Thank for answering. I didn't like ffmpeg when I used it, been experiencing too many errors with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is experiencing the same thing, I managed to do it by creating a video of the image I had and then, merge/concatenate the original video with my video that has the image in. The code;

```py
import cv2
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

image_path = '.../1.jpg'
video_path = '.../1.mp4'
image_video_path = '.../2.mp4'
frame = cv2.imread(image_path)
height, width, layers = frame.shape
video = cv2.VideoWriter(image_video_path, 0x00000021, 1, (width, height))
for i in range(2):
    video.write(frame)
video.release()

image_clip = VideoFileClip(image_video_path)
orig_video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([image_clip, orig_video_clip], method="compose")
final_clip.write_videofile('../final_video.mp4')
```

There could be improvements to be done, it's just an example to start with. I hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

Only using the `moviepy` library incase anyone need it:

```py
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
image = ImageClip("image.jpg").set_duration(1)


def crop(clip):
    clip = clip.crop(x1=420, width=1080)
    return clip


image = image.subclip(0, image.end).fx(vfx.fadeout, .5, final_color=[87, 87, 87])
clip = clip.subclip(0, clip.end).fx(vfx.fadein, .5, initial_color=[87, 87, 87])

combine = concatenate_videoclips([image, crop(clip)])

combine.write_videofile('output.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moviepy! 
Looks like it does what you want
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering! Just checked its documentation, not really what I'm looking for. It says in its documentation that it doesn't really support adding images into videos.